# Vim: How to assign a colorscheme at random from a selected list?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I have some colorschemes that I really like. I also find changing between them adds some freshness to my work. I've been changing manually for a while, but would love to automate this.

I'd like to put a line in my `.vimrc` that assigns a random colorscheme from a pre-defined whitelist. I googled around and didn't find obvious answers, and even some debate about whether there's even a `random` function in vimscript.

I don't know much vimscript, and though I've read the basics here and there over the years, I don't have a working knowledge of it because I rarely use it. So I thought I'd reach out to the community.
I tried to do this myself after some reasearch, but the following code fails:

```
let my_colorschemes = ['torte', 'Dark2' , 'ubloh']
colorscheme my_colorschemes[rand() % (len(my_colorschemes) - 1 ) ]
```

```
Cannot find color scheme 'my_colorschemes[rand() % (len(my_colorschemes)+ 1 ) ]'
```

Can anyone help me get this right? There seems to be some fundamental concepts I'm missing in vimscript...

Thanks!

-------- UPDATE ---------

For posterity, after the correct answer below, the code that works for me is:

```
let my_colorschemes = ['torte', 'Dark2' , 'ubloh', 'znake']
execute 'colorscheme' my_colorschemes[rand() % (len(my_colorschemes) - 1 ) ]
```

I guess I was close, but there's no way I would have come up with what was wrong on my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim bits are explained in User Manual (`:h user-manual`). The relevant chapter 41 "Write a Vim script" (`:h usr_41.txt`), section 41.5 (`:h 41.5`).

To put it short, only few commands accept expressions, while others accept only literal arguments (btw. this is the reason one writes `:colo torte` and not `:colo "torte"`). Therefore to compose a command dynamically one needs both to build a string representation of a command and to re-evaluate it.

So it becomes `:execute 'colo' my_colors[rand() % len(my_colors)]`